# Find the syntactic similarity of parse trees using subtree kernal appraoch of moschitti

Tags: syntax, tree, subset, similarity

I need to find syntactic similarity of sentences.For this I want to use Subset tree kernal approach of Moschitti.Kindly help me how to do in python.

Comment: Please include the relevant code that is causing the problem.

Comment: As part of my research,I have to implement Subset tree kernal method to find the similarities between two trees.But after,extensive search also i didn't find any code in python for that.Can anybody help in implementing Moschitti's subset tree kernal method in python.